# Adobe After Effects: Equal spacing between layers when each layer is a different size?

Tags: after-effects, adobe

I am working in **Adobe After Effects** (version 17.7.0 Build 45).

I have the following:

[image: screenshot of after effects]

How can I get equal spacing between the three layers when each layer is a different size? Let's say I want 60 pixels between each layer?

In other design software, it is easy, when I drag and drop, it tells me. Here's Figma for example:

[image: figma screenshot]

How can I get the same in Adobe After Effects? I already know about the Align tools in Adobe After Effects, but they do something different. For example, I couldn't say "I want 60 pixels between each layer".